# Is there anyway to find create date of existing databases in arangodb with arangosh

Tags: arangodb, arangojs

like in mysql we can query the system table/ information schema table to get databases based on creation date, is there any command or query to get databases based on database creation date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The response if you ask for the current database only contains the following information:

```
$ curl -u root: http://localhost:8529/_db/_system/_api/database/current
{
  "error": false,
  "code": 200,
  "result": {
    "name": "_system",
    "id": "1",
    "path": "C:\\ProgramData\\ArangoDB",
    "isSystem": true
  }
}
```

There is no creation date I'm afraid. Feel free to make this a [feature request](https://github.com/arangodb/arangodb/issues/new) however.

Please also include how other database systems handle this if you happen to know, especially the cluster case in which every node might have a different time.